# Chromosomal translocation notation

Tags: human-biology, genetics, dna

A reciprocal translocation is denoted for example: t(4;12)(q32;q24) indicating that q32 on chromosome 4 being swapped with q24 on chromosome 12 if I understand this correctly.

My question is: How do I know whether this is a balanced or an unbalanced translocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This translocation is balanced: if it was not there was a specific sign for specific unbalanced event, for example "del" for deletion or "+" and "-" signs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Chromosomal aberrations have defined notations you can find [here](http://www.informatics.jax.org/mgihome/nomen/anomalies.shtml).

The notation rule for multiple genetic abnormalities is to concatenate them. In the presence of an unbalanced translocation two abnormalities will be indicated as you have both a translocation and another event (e.g. deletion, duplication, ...).

In your example, as no other abnormalities/events are indicated, this is a balanced translocation.